# ERROR Error: NG0100: ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError on opening the component

Tags: javascript, angular

I have a component containing `form` with few `div` elements, the `table` and at the end of table the `button` (`Add Date` - like below).
When I show this component I get `ERROR Error: NG0100: ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError` error pointing to the :

```html
<button class="btn btn-primary" [ngClass]="{ 'disabled': !form.controls['scheduledDate'].valid }">
    Add Date
</button>
```

Can somebody help me to understand why is this happening. What is illegal about disabling button if one of the form's control is invalid?

```html
<form [formGroup]="form" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()" *ngIf="isLoaded && !isAdmin">
    ... [few div elements and a table]
    <div class="form-row" *ngIf="accountService.isAdmin()">
            
            <div class="form-group">
                <button class="btn btn-primary" [ngClass]="{ 'disabled': !form.controls['scheduledDate'].valid }">
                    Add Date
                </button>
            </div>
        </table>
    </div>
    <div class="row mt-3"></div>
</form>
```

Comment: You should probably be using `[class.disabled]="!form.controls.scheduledDate.valid"`, don't use `this` in your HTML, and if you're only setting 1 property, don't use objects.

Comment: I didn't use `this` in html - my mistake - I fixed it in the original question. Still doesn't work though

Comment: @user19564787 How about changing it to `<button class="btn btn-primary" [disabled]="!form.controls['scheduledDate'].valid">
    Add Date
</button>`

Comment: Still throws the `exception`

Comment: are you sure it is the button? The function in `*ngIf` is more likely to be evil, that the error still occur when you remove the `accountService.isAdmin()`?

Comment: You are absolutely right. I removed `accountService.isAdmin()` and the exception does not occur anymore. Problem is how do I call `accountService.isAdmin()` in other way that does not cause the exception?

Comment: You don't. The error is given because there is something binded that's changing while Angular is creating the DOM. One way to fix this problem would be to tell Angular to start rendering the HTML when you are sure that every variable is stable therefor not changing at that time.

Comment: OK. I provided a variable that is initialized in the constructor of the component that replaces `accountService.isAdmin()` - but the error is still thrown. Why?

Comment: @user19564787 share your component code, this error is thrown due to various different reasons but usually comes up when you're trying to update a property inside ngAfterViewInit(easy to fix) or after angular has already checked for changes(a bit difficult as it is vague).

Comment: I have fixed it by removing [(ngModel)] from my HTML file